# Can't dispatch action defined in store sub file

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In `/store/index.js` I have:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import auth from "./modules/auth";
```

Then in /store/modules/auth.js I have:

```
export const actions = {
  login({ commit, dispatch }, payload) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But when trying to dispatch my login() action from any component by doing `dispatch("auth/login", {})`, I get this error:

> [vuex] unknown action type: login

Why?

[EDIT] as per Shivam Singh's comment here's my export part:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: null
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    auth: {
        namespaced: true
    }
  }
});
```

After adding `auth` inside `modules: {}`, I'm getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined

Comment: Maybe you have not registered your imported 'auth' module. Also, where are you exporting the store? `export default new Vuex.Store({ modules: { auth } })` -> this line will export & register the 'auth' module.

Comment: Thanks @ShivamSingh! I added that however now I'm getting an error which doesn't make sense to me. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Did you use `namespacing` in your `auth`-module? Reference: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing

Comment: It don't get any error now. But `dispatch("auth/login", {})` still yields `unknown action type: auth/login` error :(

Comment: Is the action the only thing in `/store/modules/auth.js`? How did you set the `namespacing`?

Comment: have you tried just dispatching the action directly? `this.$store.dispatch('login', {})`

Comment: Matthias: no, in `auth.js` there's a state, mutations, etc. TJ Weems: if I do that, it will look for a `login` action located in my store root `index.js` file

Comment: @drake035, well I use the module system as well and as long as you don't have the modules scoped it will find the action...

Comment: Yes works, thanks! No idea how to make it work with namespacing...

Answer (score 0):

/store/modules/auth.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import auth from "./modules/auth";

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    token: null
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {},
  modules: {
    auth: { // it's registry name, will be used while accessing module content.
        namespaced: true,
        ...auth // actual module content.
    }
  }
});
```

> While registering the module, you are not providing the actual module
>   content.

Ref vue doc: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing